# Why isn't ConstexprIterator from std::array bidirectional/random-access?

Tags: c++, iterator, constexpr

I have a library function that works on arbitrary containers. Basically it prints elements. For a bidirectional/random-access container it prints first and last, for unidirectional only first. Recognizing and using bidirectionality hinges on a working `--container.end()`. This worked for `std::array` in C++17, but in C++20 `std::array` has `ConstexprIterator` instead of `LegacyRandomAccessIterator`.
Reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ConstexprIterator it seems that `ConstexprIterator` really doesn't have `operator--` and instead has something to do with cats???

[image]

So my question is: WHY isn't `ConstexprIterator` random-access or at least bidirectional? I mean, if it works at compile time then it really should be random-access.

Comment: LOL :D, good finding. Maybe an incomplete article about that feature. Worth to cite in your question, or taking a screenshot.

Comment: I see Stephan T. Lavavej has been having fun again :)

Comment: fwiw, cppreference isnt an official document. You can see the edits made [here](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/named_req/ConstexprIterator&action=history) and the cat stuff came in [here](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp%2Fnamed_req%2FConstexprIterator&diff=119335&oldid=119328)

Comment: `operator--` is an operation on `It` that is required to be supported by `RandomAccessIterator`. Would you rather have it use Foo and Bar instead of Purr and Meow?

Comment: `--arr.end()` doesn't compile, but `auto it = arr.end(); --it;` does. The first confused me and I wrongly blamed ConstexprIterator. Re catness - now that I know it means "It can do everything that underlying(?/main/other/...) iterator can but in constexpr" it makes sense. Maybe still to much language lawyer speech for me. Also it wasn't obvious to me (before) that iterator can be ConstexprIterator AND other at the same time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> in c++20 `std::array` has *ConstexprIterator* instead of *LegacyRandomAccessIterator*

Not "instead of".

> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array (bold mine)
>
> `iterator` — *LegacyRandomAccessIterator* **and** *ConstexprIterator* (since C++20) that is a *LiteralType* (since C++17)

---

> WHY isn't *ConstexprIterator* random access or at least bidirectional

An iterator can have any iterator category in addition to being *ConstexprIterator*.

*ConstexprIterator* requires that all operations required by a category (that an iterator claims to conform to) work at compile-time, nothing more.

<sup><sub><sub>Meow!</sub></sub></sup>

Answer (score 6):

> So my question is: WHY isn't ConstexprIterator random access or at least bidirectional?

Because that would prevent iterators that aren't random access or bidirectional from being *constexpr iterators*. Such limitation would be undesirable.

This is similar to how neither *mutable iterator* nor *constant iterator* are limited to certain iterator category. These are additional concepts that can apply to iterator of *any* category.

> Reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ConstexprIterator it seems that ConstexprIterator really doesn't have operator--

Regadless of the linked page being out of date (and a non-normative source), this is actually true. A *constexpr iterator* doesn't necessarily have operator--.

> Why ConstexprIterator from std::array isn't bidirectional/random access?

It **is** random access. Standard says (latest draft):

> [array.overview]
>
> The header  defines a class template for storing fixed-size sequences of objects. An array is a contiguous container.

> [container.requirements.general]
>
> A contiguous container is a container whose member types iterator and const_­iterator meet the Cpp17RandomAccessIterator requirements ([random.access.iterators]) and model contiguous_­iterator ([iterator.concept.contiguous]).